# Checking a MySQL connection and refreshing it

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using the following function to check if a MySQL connection is in an invalid state or if it has reached a predefined maximum operation count:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Holds the amount of operations for the currently mysql-connection open
 /// </summary>
 private int connectionUsageCount = 0;

 /// <summary>
 /// The maximum usage count of the connection until it has to be refreshed
 /// </summary>
 private const int MAX_CONNECTION_USAGE_COUNT = 100;

 /// <summary>
 /// Holds the cached MySql Connection to the databse server.
 /// </summary>
 private MySqlConnection mySqlConnection;

 /// <summary>
 /// Checks the status of the sql connection and refreshes it when necessary.
 /// </summary>
 private void CheckSqlConnection()
 {
     // Check if the connection is in an invalid state or
     // the connection has to be refreshed and refresh it
     // when necessary
     if (mySqlConnection == null
         || mySqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken
         || mySqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed
         || connectionUsageCount >= MAX_CONNECTION_USAGE_COUNT)
     {
         // If the connection was already initialized, close and dispose it
         if (mySqlConnection != null)
         {
             // If connection is open, close it
             if (mySqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken
                 && mySqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
             {
                 mySqlConnection.Close();
             }

             mySqlConnection.Dispose();
             mySqlConnection = null;
         }

         // Create new connection 
         mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Can anyone review this piece of code and tell provide me with some feedback? I am not sure if I have covered all possibilities that would cause an error when using the `mySqlConnection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567097/using-mysqlconnection-in-c-sharp-does-not-close-properly) you need to be aware that calling `Close` will not necessarily actually close the connection but only put it back into the connection pool.
2. There is no reason to do `mySqlConnection = null;`. You assign a new value to `mySqlConnection` in the next statement so setting it to `null` achieves nothing.
3. [These docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-close) might be somewhat out-dated but they state that you can call `Close` multiple times and that no exception is generated so you can probably skip the check and just call `Close` unconditionally.

Comment: how about a simple re-binder

   if (MySQLcon.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) MySQLcon.Open();